# How to generte archetype for Neon relese?

Tags: opendaylight

I am trying to generate an archetype so I can update my project to the Neon release. I tried:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.opendaylight.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=opendaylight-startup-archetype  -DarchetypeRepository=https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/ -DarchetypeVersion=1.8.0
```

The instructions on the how to page don't work either. (It is unfortunate that the first step an aspiring developer would take does not work.)

https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-neon/developer-guide/developing-apps-on-the-opendaylight-controller.html

How do I generate an archetype for opendaylight neon. I can't find workable instructions on the ODL website.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. After some trial and error, I found out that version 1.5.4 of opendaylight-startup-archetype in org.opendaylight.controller atleast creates the right folders.

Unfortunately, building it gives errors in the artifacts, features and karaf .pom files. But maybe this gets You a bit further.